# Angular 4 error: There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: angular

I am getting following error in my Angular 4 project after ng serve command.

> ./src/app/Utils/config.service.ts
>   There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
>   This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
>   Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\src\app\Utils\config.service.ts
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\src\app\utils\email.service.ts
>   * D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\src\app\utils\config.service.ts
>       Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
>       D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!D:\ANGULAR\siteprice.org\src\app\app.module.ts

config.service.ts file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  _apiURI : string;

  constructor() {
      this._apiURI = 'http://www.example.com/xyz/api/';
    }

    getApiURI() {
        return this._apiURI;
    }

    getApiHost() {
        return this._apiURI.replace('api/','');
    }

}
```

email.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ConfigService } from '../Utils/config.service';
import { Email } from '../Models/email';

@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  apiRoot: string = '';

  constructor(private http: Http, private configService: ConfigService) { 
    this.apiRoot = configService.getApiURI();
  }
```

I checked casing of the service names and they are correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the issue and I think it may be a bug in CLI.

The Utils folder name should be utils. So the first letter is lower case.
utils folder in my windows directory is created with lower case.
So I changed this:

```
import { ConfigService } from '../Utils/config.service';
```

to:

```
import { ConfigService } from '../utils/config.service';
```

**Edit:**

It looks like this is a known issue, one of the suggested solution is using kebap case file, folder names in windows.

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/926